# Spaces in a URL when using requests and python

Tags: python, curl, request

I hope I can explain myself. with out making an arse of myself.

I am trying to use python 3.4 to send a url to a sparkcore api.

I have managed to use curl direcly from the windows command line:-

```
curl https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/led -d access_token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy -d params=l1,HIGH
```

All works fine. there is a space between the `led` and `-d`, but that is not a problem.

I have read that `reting` to do this within python using `libcurl` is a big pain and I saw lots of messaged about using Requests, so I though I would give it a go.

So I wrote a small routine:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/led -d access_token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy -d params=l1,HIGH')
print(r.url)
print(r)
```

I get as return:

```
<Response [400]>
```

When I examine the URL which actually got sent out the spaces in the URL are replaced with %20. This seems to be my actual problem, because the %20 being added by requests are confusing the server which fails

> "code": 400,
>   "error": "invalid_request",
>   "error_description": "The access token was not found"

I have tried reading up on how to inpractice have the spaces with out having a %20 being added by the encoding, but I really could do with a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks

Liam

Comment: Can you reword the question? I don't think your explanation is clear.

Comment: that %20 is the REST interpretation of a space character and it's how google reads it when you put a set of search terms in your url bar.  urls don't have spaces in them.  Why does yours?

Comment: I never actaully added the %20's I did use spaces in my url, and that worked fine with curl in the windows command line, If I copy and paste the identical url in to the Requests command the python script fails, and when I use print(r.url) the spaces are replaced by %20, in the responce I get back from Requests.

Comment: The url ends at led, starting at -d are options sent to curl. Requests expects the first argument to be only the url.

Comment: Ok, and hence the -d means PUT xxxxxx to the url.. So I need to figure out how to send options... Looking through the requests.org websire, I am having trouble seeing how to do that... But my brains are starting to melt now..

Comment: Actually it means POST xxxxxx to the url. Requests is very easy to use, for a [post](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) you just need to pass it a dictionary with your data.

Answer (score 1):

URLs cannot have spaces. The curl command you are using is actually making a request to the url `https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/led` with some command line arguments (using `-d`)

The [curl man (manual) page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) says this about the `-d` command line argument

*-d, --data*

*(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.*

*-d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.*

*If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.*

*If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out.*

So that says `-d` is for sending data to the URL with the POST request using the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The requests documentation has a good example of how to do that using the requests library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

So for your curl command, I think this should work

```
import requests
payload = {'access_token': 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', 'params': 'l1,HIGH'}
r = requests.post("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/led", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thats it on the nail, thats what I was trying to do. Thanks. I had started to look at the payload option, but it was getting a bit fuzzy in my head, particularly as it was getting late. Also you comments detailing the inherit limitations of curl/urls (no spaces), brought things in to focus. Having a worked example has really pulled it together. Thanks again. Thats is answered nicely.